# How to combine two dictionaries using python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
import csv

def partytoyear():
    party_in_power = {}
    with open("presidents.txt") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            party = row[1]
            for year in row[2:]:
                party_in_power[year] = party

    print(party_in_power)
    return party_in_power



partytoyear()



def statistics():

    with open("BLS_private.csv") as f:
        statistics = {}
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            statistics = row
        print(statistics)   
        return statistics


statistics()
```

These two functions return two dictionaries.

Here is a sample of the first dictionary:

```
'Democrat', '1981': 'Republican', '1982': 'Republican', '1983'
```

Sample of the second dictionary:

```
'2012', '110470', '110724', '110871', '110956', '111072', '111135', '111298', '111432', '111560', '111744'
```

The first dictionary associates a year and the political party. The next dictionary associates the year with job statistics.

I need to combine these two dictionaries, so I can have the party inside the dictionary with the job statistics.

I would like the dictioary to look like this:

```
'Democrat, '2012','110470', '110724', '110871', '110956', '111072', '111135', '111298', '111432', '111560', '111744'
```

How would I go about doing this? I've looked at the syntax for update() but that didn't work for my program

Answer (score 0):

You can’t have a dictionary in that manor in python it’s syntactically wrong but you can have each value be a collection such as a list. Here’s a comprehension that does just that using dict lookups:

```
first_dict = {'Democrat': '1981': 'Republican': '1982': 'Republican': '1983', ...}
second_dict = {'2012': ['110470', '110724', '110871', '110956', '111072', '111135', '111298', '111432', '111560', '111744'], ...}

result = {party: [year, *second_dict[year] for party, year in first_dict.items()}
```

Pseudo result dict structure:

```
{'Party Name': [year, stats, ...], ...}
```

Comment: i get a key error.. is there something i am missing?